# My PC restarts with NO Warning!I am using ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, restart

My pc restarts automatically, where should I look first for a solution?Thanks

Comment: Check your BIOS settings first,  e.g CPU temperature limits

Comment: Usually this kind of action is hardware related. ie: video card and such. Check your video card and memory sticks for proper fitment. Re-seat the card and sticks. Make sure you have good ventilation and the heat sinks are clean and fans are working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue and couldn't seem to track it down. It ended up being heat related , it wasn't my CPU overheating but something else on my motherboard causing the random reboot. In this case, the system would poweroff instantly, then restart itself. I stumbled upon the answer by taking off the case side and pointing a box fan at it.