# Ubuntu 12.04 restarts automatically

Tags: 12.04, overheating, restart, automatic

I am running a program which takes several days at a stretch in my ubuntu 12.04 desktop. I find my pc restarted sometimes. There is no specific pattern to it. Sometimes the first day or sometimes the third, etc.

I am using 3 threads of my i-5 processor to run the program. I have 11 GB of ram and I am hardly using 4 GB ram thoughout the runtime of the program.

I saw similar restarting issues in

[My PC restarts with NO Warning!I am using ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127569/my-pc-restarts-with-no-warningi-am-using-ubuntu-12-04)

where it says it could be temperature related. I plan to monitor the temperature of my processors next time I run the program, but it is unlikely that it is overheating in well air-conditioned room (I could be wrong!).

**Is there a way to check the log files to say what caused the restart?**

I am currently trying to tweak my program to create temporary restore points in the event of a system crash/restart. I would very much like to understand what is happening from the ubuntu side of things.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the folder `/var/log/` where you can find all log files. Check `syslog` for the system log

Comment: I previously looked at kern.log before but not the syslog. It didn't help much though. All I see is my wifi coneection going berserk before the computer restarted.